# FindResource gives error 1813 on exe file

Tags: c++, c, winapi, embedded-resource

I have been trying this for like the last 3 days and I still can't make it work. The WINAPI `FindResource` function throws and error 1813: this means that the resource type is not found. I am using eclipse so there is no .RC file or resource.h file so I have loaded my exe file with `LoadLibraryA` and then used the `HANDLE` in `FindResourceA`. Here is my code:

```
HRSRC hRsrc;
HMODULE hExe;

/** Loading resource file in the program */
if (!(hExe = LoadLibraryA(TEXT(filename)))) {
    printf("Cannot load resource error: %lu \n", GetLastError());
    return 0;
}
printf("Resource file %s is loaded to the program \n", filename);

/** Finding resource */
if (!(hRsrc = FindResourceA(hExe, MAKEINTRESOURCE(10), "EXE"))) {
    printf("Cannot find resource error: %lu \n", GetLastError());
    return 0;
}
puts("Resource found");
```

Now, from what I understand is that the `MAKEINTRESOURCE(10)` lets us define a custom resource. Is this correct or I am just taking it wrong? In the resource type I tried giving "EXE" "BIN" "Exehead" and `RT_RCDATA`but nothing works, and it still gives me the same error as before. All the solution's on the web are with `.RC` and `resource.h` files on `Visual Studio`, is there anything to work with eclipse? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load a specific resource from a binary, you need to know the resource's type and its id.

If either one of those or both is not know you can use the function `EnumResourceTypes()` and/or `EnumResourceNames()` to find out.

An example on how to use `EnumResourceTypes()` can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Creating_a_Resource_List

---

**Update:**

If the resource editor provided by MS is not available this **free** tool might help: http://www.resedit.net/ I used to use it and worked for my needs. Anyhow, I do not know its current state.

Comment: @KeshavNair: You also might like to have a look at the tool mentioned in my update.

Answer (score 2):

The error is correct. There is no resource of type `"EXE"` in your file. You said so yourself when you say that you don't have an `.RC` file. Resources are defined in `.RC` files, and if you don't have one, then you have no resources. To add a resource of type `"EXE"` with resource ID 10, you need to create an `.RC` file, add it to your project, and say

```
10 EXE "somefile"
```

where "somefile" is some file whose contents you want to use as the resource data.

If your IDE does not support `.RC` files then you will not be able to add resources via the IDE. You will have to add them some other way, say, via a postprocessing step.

But the point is that you are getting the error "resource type not found" because you did nothing to create a resource of that type. What did you expect?

Comment: Sorry but i want to know that if there is another way around to add a resource or make it work and i think yes i cannot add .RC file in eclipse

Comment: @KeshavNair But that wasn't the question you asked. You asked, "Why doesn't FindResource find my resource?" The answer is "Because you never added the resource, so there was nothing to find." If your question is actually, "How do I add a resource in eclipse?" then you should have asked that question instead.

Answer (score 1):

(*

Remember: When You start a new Project....
Delphi adds {$R *.res} to your .dpr file to link the .res file that it generates into your application.
E.g. if you save your project as MyProject.dpr, Delphi will create a file MyProject.res that contains your application icon and version information that you specify in Project Options in Delphi. Without this .res file, your .exe won't have an icon or version info AND YOU'LL GET 1813.[EG.: from GetFileVersionInfoSize( PChar( @sFileName[ 1 ] ), 0); ]

If you get a duplicate resource warning, you probably have another {$R} compiler directive elsewhere  in your code that also links in MyProject.res. It could be a duplicate {$R *.res} in your .dpr file, or a {$R MyProject.res} in another .pas file. (Just) Delete the other compiler directive instead of the one that Delphi generates automatically, and your project will compile just fine.
*)